# PHP Copy function slower than linux cp command when copying from remote NFS share

Tags: php, linux, cp

I have been trying to copy an audio file from `nfs share` on another server. When I use `PHP` to copy the it takes 5.5 seconds to copy an 8 MB audio file. However when I use the cp command in the shell it takes 0.845 seconds.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is and how to fix it?

```
<?php
  $result = copy('/remote/dir/remoteFile.wav’,’12345.wav');
  var_dump($returnVar);
?>
```

Comment: Did you try to use the `cp` command just after doing it in PHP? If so, the file is most likely in disk cache giving you a different result when testing.

Comment: @HonkyTonk Possibly true but 8MB in 5 seconds is ~12.5 Mb/s with overheads which over a local network would be incredibly slow. Is this file being copied over a LAN or the internet (don't forget to take VPNs etc into account)? Is it possible this was due to a noisy network? Is this massive difference in the time repeatedly reproducible?

Comment: I'd be quite interested to see what result you get if you try running `cp` by shelling out of PHP `exec("cp file newLocation")` or somesuch.

Comment: I tried `exec('cp ..')` instead; however it took another 20ms to do the copy. I have made lots of copys on the remote server with different filenames. So when do the tests I change source and destination filename.

Comment: Just guessing: Might the difference be that the PHP engine is wrapping each read/write cycle in some kind of flush? This would be very different from how the `cp` command works.

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can be certain the the PHP copy will be slower than linux cp because one uses native OS level calls, and the other is application layer which invokes the same through the web server et al. Too many layers to go through, notifications to process, protocols to adhere to etc etc.. I do not think this is exactly **fixable**..

Maybe instead of a `copy()` you could try an `exec('cp ..')` command which will directly try to run the linux cp command from php. Might not give you as much speed as `cp from shell`, but might make it a bit more faster than `copy() from php`. Give it a try..

Comment: Thanks I had tried `exec('cp ..')` however it took another 20ms to do the copy. (I know 20ms is not a lot)

Comment: `shell_exec` is a bit faster